# Minimise width of the multi-line text in Flutter

Tags: text, flutter, flutter-layout

[image: Example]

I have a variable-width container (screen width) and fixed left and right margins. Remaining area gives me a constraint for maximum text width, where I'm placing text of variable content (multiple languages). I want text to fit into that width without truncation, wrapping if needed. Text is relatively short - it may fit into single line, likely to fit into 2 lines and will fit into 3 lines for sure.

I want to avoid cases like (2) - where text wraps into long and a short line. It does not look nice. Instead I would like it to wrap more evenly, like in case (3).

For the demo purposes I've hardcoded hand-picked margins, but I want solution to work automatically for any text content and any container width.

Is it achievable using built-in Flutter widgets, or I need to implement something custom, similar to https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/auto_size_text?